# how to find End of File in multi-line input in Java STDIN

Tags: java

Below code shows how to accept multi-line input from console.But in this case I am not able to provide EOF for inputs for processing the results. So the program is not compiling. Please suggest some ways to resolve the issue.

```
package Controller;

import java.util.*;
public class Multi_Line_Input
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the inputs");
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            l.add(line);
        }
        Iterator i = l.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println((String)i.next());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your compiler error?

Comment: There is no EOF on the console. It’s not clear what you want. I have downvoted for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? When you type **exit** it will stop the program and print the lines that you inputted.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Multi_Line_Input
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the inputs");
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        String line = s.nextLine();

        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            break;
        }

        l.add(line);
    }
    Iterator i = l.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println((String)i.next());
    }
}

}
```